# Symmetric-decreasing rearrangement of a function

Tags: measure-theory, symmetry, decreasing-rearrangements

I'm studying [section 3.3](http://books.google.ch/books?id=S-CGnXWy0HcC&lpg=PA188&dq=symmetric%20decreasing%20rearrangement%20lieb%20loss&hl=fr&pg=PA80#v=onepage&q&f=false) of *Analysis* by Lieb and Loss, about symmetric-decreasing rearrangement of functions.

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a Borel set of finite Lebesgue measure. They define
>   $A^*$ to be the ball centered at 0 with the same measure that
>   $A$.
>
> The symmetric-decreasing rearrangement of a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is then defined by
>
> $$f^*(x):=\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{\{|f|>t\}^*}(x)dt,$$
>
> by comparison to the "layercake" representation of $f$, namely
>   $$f(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \chi_{\{f>t\}}(x)dt.$$

They say that it is then an obvious property that

$$\{x: f^*(x)>t\}=\{x: |f(x)|>t\}^* .$$

But I can't see why/how...

Comment: Your statement is a bit suspect: if $A^*$ has the same measure as $A$, $A^*$ most likely will **not** be the _unit_ ball. It will just be a ball.

Comment: I think that some $t$'s in your definitions should be replaced by $x$'s.

Comment: Fixed, thanks and sorry for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint 1: show that if $t_1 > t_2$, then $\{ |f| > t_1\}^* \subseteq \{ |f| > t_2\}^*$.

Hint 2: use this to show that if $y\in \{ |f| > t \}^*$, then $y \in \{|f| > s\}^*$ for every $0 \leq s \leq t$. Notice that this implies that $f^*(y) \geq t$ by the definition.

Hint 3: use hint 1 again to show that if $y\not\in \{|f| > t\}^*$, 
$$ \sup \left\{ s \geq 0 ~~|~~ y \in \{|f| > s\}^*\right\} \leq t $$
this implies in particular $f^*(y) \leq t$ (why?).

Comment: hint 3 is unnecessary. You already proved that the level set of $f^{*}$ is subset of the star set.

Comment: It seems that you only showed $\{ f^*>t\} \subset \{ |f|>t\}^*$. But how to show the another side.

Comment: @IMOS: Reading literally what I wrote 11 years ago: Hint 2 leads to  "$\{ |f| > t \}^*  \subseteq \{ f^* \geq t \}$" // Hint 3 is meant to lead to the other  direction (the one you mentioned in your comment) // I do not understand the comment by TKM.

Comment: @WillieWong Yes, I found that you showed $\{|f|>t\}^*\subset \{ f^*\ge t\}$. And we need more explanation to show that $\{|f|>t\}^*\subset \{ f^*\ge t\} \subset \{f^*>t\}$. I just found this can be done by the continuous of Lebesgue measure. (By showing $\{f*=t\} is of zero measure$. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 7):

Fix $t>0$ et $y\in \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}$. This  is equivalent to say that
$$c_d|y|^d<|\{|f|>t\}|,\qquad \qquad c_d=|B(0,1)|. $$
Assume that
$$\int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds=0.$$
Then $y\not \in \{|f| > s\}^{*}$ for all $s\geq t$.
That is, for all $s\geq t$ we have
$$c_d|y|^d\geq |\{|f|>s\}| $$
The Fatou lemma implies
$$c_d|y|^d\geq |\{|f|\geq t\}|\geq |\{|f|>t\}|.$$
This is in contradiction with the fact that $c_d|y|^d<|\{|f|>t\}|$. Therefore we deduce $$\int_{t}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds>0.$$
On the other hand, one can check that for every, $0<s< t$ one has $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}\subset \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}$$ this entails that,
\begin{equation}\label{eq-inclu t-s}\tag{I}
\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}\subset \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}~~~\textrm{for all $s\in (0,t)$}.
\end{equation}
this implies that,$$ \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y)  =1 ~~~s\in (0,t)$$

From definition of $f^{*}$,  if $y\in \{|f|>t\}^*$ then we have
$$\begin{align*}
f^{*}(y) &:= \int_{0}^{+ \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds\\
&= \int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds+ \int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds\\
& = \int_{0}^{t} ds+\int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds >t.
\end{align*}$$

Whence, $$\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}\subset \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n:f^{*}(x)> t \right\}.$$
Conversely, suppose, $y\notin \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}$. If $t\leq s$ then analogously to relation \eqref{eq-inclu t-s} we get
$$y\notin \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}.$$
That is for all $s\geq t$ we get  $$\mathbf{1}_{\{ | f| > s\}^*}(y)=0$$
Hence necessarily for all $s>0$ such that
$ y\in \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}$ one has $0<s\leq t$. This means that,
$$\sup\left\{s>0 : y\in \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > s  \right\}^{*}\right\}\leq t. $$
We then deduce that,
$$\begin{align*}
f^{*}(y) &:= \int_{0}^{+ \infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds\\
&= \int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds+ \underbrace{\int_{t}^{+\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\left\{ | f| > s \right\}^*}(y) ds}_{=0}\leq t
\end{align*}$$
that is  $f^*(y)\leq t$ or that $y\notin \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: f^*(x) > t  \right\}$. We've just prove that,

\begin{equation}\label{eq}\tag{II}
\Bbb R^n\setminus \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |f(x)| > t  \right\}^{*}\subset \Bbb R^n\setminus\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: f^*(x) > t \right\}. 
\end{equation}
Which ends the prove by taking the complementary.

Comment: Nice answer. I am amused that the authors see this as "obvious" (of course it is if you look at a picture...).

Comment: I am delighted that someone finally finds this answer useful

Comment: It looks like that you can only get $f^*(y)\ge t$ in your first part, and you need more explanation to show $f^*(y)\neq t$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1997959/on-rearrangement-of-level-set-ft-ft-text?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @GuyFsone for the very clear solution. I didn't understand the final step. How to conclude that $\int_0^t \chi_{\{|f| > s\}^\ast} (y) ds \leq t$ ?  Is it true just because $\chi_{\{|f| > s\}^\ast} (y) \leq 1 ?$ Or do we have to use the supremum ?

Comment: @GuyFsone do you know where can I find a proof for the question in the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4866925/inequality-involving-the-l2-norm-of-the-gradient-of-the-symmetric-decreasing  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this subject for some months now and your question was one of the main obstacles I encountered. I think what makes this particular problem hard to attack is that it seems so obvious and geometrically correct that most would prefer not to bother with a formal proof. Anyway, what worked for me was proving first that
$$ r(t) = C_n\sqrt[n]{\mathcal{L}^n\left(\{ |f| > t \}\right)} $$
where $C_n = \left( \frac{n\Gamma(n/2)}{2\pi^{n/2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$, is a lower semicontinuous function. Then you can prove that the parameter $t$ in the integral which defines $f^*$ will define a set that contains $x$ just in an OPEN interval. Showing that it is an interval is pretty easy, but the open part is where you need the lower semicontinuity of the function $r$.

Best regards!