# Lebesgue measure and Integral problems

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

[image: Question]

. (a) Let $f : \mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ be measurable, and assume that 
$$\int f\,dm < \infty,$$ where $m$ is the
Lebesgue measure. Prove that there is a nonincreasing function $g : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$
such that
$$
m(\{x : f(x) < a\}) = m(\{x : g(x) < a\})\text{ for all }a > 0.
$$
(b) Prove that if $f, g : [0, 1] → [0,\infty)$ are two measurable functions such that (a) holds,
then $$\int_{[0,1]} f\, dm = \int_{[0,1]} g\,dm$$.

Thank you so much. I just have no idea how to start.

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99564/symmetric-decreasing-rearrangement-of-a-function

Comment: @Bungo, could you please eloborate more on that? I got quite confused