# A proof of Pólya-Szegő inequality

Tags: measure-theory, symmetry, symmetric-functions, weak-lp-spaces, decreasing-rearrangements

Denote by $|A|$ the $N-$dimensional Lebesgue measure of a Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and define
$$
A^\ast := B_{R}(0), \quad R = \left(\frac{N}{\omega_N}|A| \right)^{\frac{1}{N}},
$$
where $\omega_N$ is the surface measure of $S^{N-1}$. It is known that $|A| = |A^\ast|$. The symmetric-decreasing rearrangement of the characteristic function $\chi_A$ is defined by
$$
(\chi_A)^\ast = \chi_{A^\ast}.
$$
Now, for $f \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ we define, for $t > 0$ the set $A_t = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N : |f(x)| > t\}$ and the function
$$
f^\ast(x) = \int_0^\infty (\chi_{A_t})^\ast (x) dt.
$$
In other words,
$$
f^\ast(x) = \int_0^\infty \chi_{A_t^\ast} (x) dt.
$$
It is also also known that $f^\ast$ is nonnegative, radially symmetric and nonincreasing.  As a reference I am using the book Analysis from Elliott H. Lieb and Michael Loss, page 81. I am looking for a proof of the inequality
$$
\|\nabla f ^\ast\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)} \leq \|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)}
$$
whenever $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Or more general,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla f^\ast|^p \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla f|^p,
$$
for any $p > 1$. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is known as the Polya-Szego inequality whose proof uses the co-area formula see for instance: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya%E2%80%93Szeg%C5%91_inequality).

See also the monographs: [Symmetric Decreasing Rearrangement Is Sometimes Continuous Frederick J. Almgren, Jr., Elliott H. Lieb](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1990893)

For more details see the book: [Baernstein II, Albert:
Symmetrization in analysis, 2019](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/symmetrization-in-analysis/9AE232062CC3EC6A585A3F2E3149D67D).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I take the moment to ask if is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |x|^k |f(x)|^p dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |x|^k |f^\ast(x)|^p dx$, where $f^\ast$ is the same rearrangement as before ?

Comment: @ThiagoGM I am not sure about this statement.